# I am getting replace was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, string, function

This is a function I am writing that switches the characters  of a string, but I am getting "replace was not declared in this scope".

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string rs(string j)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int len = j.size();
    int ran1 = rand() % len;

    srand(time(NULL) + 1);

    int ran2 = rand() % len;

    replace(j, ran1, ran2);

    cout << j << endl;

    return j;
}
```

Obviously I have something wrong with the function.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the function replace declared?

Comment: Which function are you trying to use?

Comment: You don't need to use `srand` twice.  Calling it once at the beginning of the program is sufficient.

Comment: Where is `replace` defined?  Are you trying to use `string::replace`? (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: Don't use `srand(time(NULL))`, in fact [just don't use `rand`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: Read that documentation carefully. Also have a look [at this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` is a member function of the `string` class which is most probably why you're getting the error.

But also, `replace()` doesn't switch the substrings, it just replaces one with the other.

If you want to switch two substrings of a string using the `replace` function, you can try doing it by replacing the line:

```
replace(j, ran1, ran2);
```

with

```
string substr_at_ran1 = j.substr(ran1, 1);
j.replace(ran1, 1, j.substr(ran2, 1));
j.replace(ran2, 1, substr_at_ran1);
```

This is switching the substring of `j` starting at position `ran1` and length `1` with a substring of `j` at position `ran2` and length `1`.

Comment: In the future, please use ` instead of italics when indicating code.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information was provided to properly answer the question, but I'll take a stab at it.

The `replace()` function I'm assuming is a function that probably doesn't exist in your program, since you didn't provide it.

Assuming that you want your function `rs()` to randomly swap two characters, here is a program that does just that.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string rs(string j)
{
    auto len = j.size();

    if (len == 0) //added because your code didn't account for empty strings
    {
        return j;
    }

    auto ran1 = rand() % len;
    auto ran2 = rand() % len;

    swap(j[ran1], j[ran2]);

    cout << j << endl;

    return j;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //do not use srand in modern C++!

    rs("stack overflow");
}
```

I would also advise against making function names like `rs`, since its functionality cannot be gleaned from the name alone.  `swap_random_characters` would be a better name.

Comment: Easier to do `std::swap(s[a], s[b]);`, that gives you a hint that `replace` is not a great name for that function.